# WSO2ESB - Add Complex SOAP Header to Request

Tags: soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I want to add complex SOAP Header to request in WSO2ESB. With Header mediator only simple valued headers can be added. How can i add complex SOAP Header to request in WSO2ESB?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB, will support adding complex xml headers from next major release. 
You can use enrich mediator as an alternative.

Please refer sample #15.
http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/4.0.3/docs/samples/message_mediation_samples.html#Sample15

Comment: This given link is dead.